# CodeIgniter form validation - how to make it case insensitive

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using Code Igniter 2, and the following code doesn't validate in case the user entered the same email address but in different cases, for example:  email@bob.com and Email@bob.com
I want this to validate if it's the same email even if the user used different cases.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{

    $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
}
else
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Any PHP function which accepts one parameter can be used in the validation class.

From [the manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingdata)

> Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a
> rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.

Which means you can just amend your validation rule to

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|strtolower|trim');
```

Note the use of the [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/strtolower) function in the rules.

Comment: I've not tested it but the manual still documents it working and the [changelog](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html) doesn't list any changes to the form validation class. In fact, the last major change was at 2.1.0 so I suspect it will still work.

Comment: Indeed, i guess i made a mistake before. Thank you, i'll check it again later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a callback function inside your controller:

```
function valid_case_insensitive_email($str){
    $str = strtolower($str)
    return $this->form_validation->valid_email($str)
}
```

Then modify the set_rules to this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback_valid_case_insensitive_email|trim');
```

Alternatively you could extend the form_validation class and overwrite the `valid_email` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do this as:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|callback__check_email');

//then the callback function

function _check_email() {
  $email = strtolower($this->input->post("email");
  $email = trim($email);
  return $this->form_validation->valid_email($email);
}
```

Hope it helps